# What are the things django will do for the installed apps?

Tags: python, django, django-apps

For example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ( 
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
    'southtut',
    'southtut2',
)
```

And `south` is a module I installed to my python envrionment.

The `southtut` and `southtut2` is the django apps I created use `./manage.py startapp`

And I am curious about the things django will do for the installed app. Is it just add the module to sys.path?

What shoult I do if I want to install a app to my django project but don't add it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list.

Comment: You won't be able to use static contents and templates within folders of every app you didn't add to `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 0):

The difference is when the use of its capabilities of django.

For example:

- when you want to creating models of app
- when you want to explore app models from admin page
- when you want to access to view of app from url patterns of it.
- when you want to test your app

Answer (score 0):

Django use the `INSTALLED_APPS` for various things. Basically, if an app wants to provide something which will be used by a core Django feature, is has to be added to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Examples include:

- Models: Django loads the models for all installed applications.

  - If you want to refer to a Model in an app from another app by name, the first app must be installed.
  - These also are the models which will appear in the Django Admin interface.
  - This also ensures reverse relationships are created or signals are connected as early as possible.
- Templates: with the default configuration, Django searches for templates in the "templates" directories of installed apps. See [TEMPLATE_LOADERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-loaders).
- Static files: "collectstatic", "findstatic" and the development static file server will search the installed apps for static files. See [STATICFILES_FINDERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders)
- Translations are discovered from installed apps too. See [How Django discovers translations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations).
- [Django Management Commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) will be discovered in installed apps too.

The list can probably be extended.

Note that an app not added to `INSTALLED_APPS` can still be useful, for example:

- Importing `urls` and using the views will work fine.
- Since Django 1.6, test discovery is no longer restricted to installed apps, see [Discovery of tests in any test module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#discovery-of-tests-in-any-test-module).